# defining variable, invalid identifier. Euclidean Distance

Tags: sql, oracle, with-statement

oracle keeps rejecting anything i try call longitude within the with clause.

```
 WITH params as (
      SELECT -28 as lat, 151 as lon
      FROM dual
     )
SELECT sighting_id 
FROM sightings 
ORDER BY sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude, 2));
```

Comment: show us your db schema. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define the params in the WITH, but never reference it in the FROM.

```
WITH params as (
      SELECT -28 as lat, 151 as lon
      FROM dual
     )
SELECT sighting_id 
FROM sightings CROSS JOIN params 
ORDER BY sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude, 2));
```